# Why do I not have the reference ID of the entity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, orm, typeorm

I have two simple entites in TypeORM with `One To One` connections. If I make a `POST` request, I get the tables, but the reference `ID` remains `null`. Why is that?

Main User Entity:

```
@Entity({ name: "user" })
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @OneToOne(
    (type) => Personal,
    (personal) => personal.user,
    { cascade: true }
  )
  @JoinColumn()
  personalId: personal;
}
```

Personal entity:

```
@Entity({ name: "personal" })
export class Personal {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  familyName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  additionalName: string;

  @OneToOne(
    (type) => User,
    (user) => user.personalId
  )
  user: User;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to set `eager: true` but nothing changed.
I had tried to set `nullable: false` and had removed the existing database, but then when I tried POST nothing happaned.

Answer (score 2):

You specified `cascade: true` in your OneToOne decorator, which means when you save a user with a given person, the person will also be save.
When you load the user, you need to specify that the data for person needs to be joined. Otherwise the person entity will be persisted, be not loaded when you get a user. In your case this could be done by setting eager to true:

```
  @OneToOne(
    (type) => Personal,
    (personal) => personal.user,
    { cascade: true, eager: true }
  )
  @JoinColumn()
  personalId: personal;
```

If you want to use the querybuilder, this will work:

```
const queryBuilder = entityManager.createQueryBuilder(User, 'user');
queryBuilder.leftJoinAndSelect('user.person', 'person');
return queryBuilder.getMany();
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it didn't work. I tried to use it both side of the relation, but in both case I got null for the ID too, and when I tried a GET regquest, I did't get the data of Personal.

Comment: Ok, then there might be a problem while saving the personal data. Did you verify that the personal data was successfully stored in the database? Can you post some more code, e.g. how you save and how you query your data?

Comment: I have updated the question with the controller and service file (Post and Save methods).

Comment: Ok, this should work. One last try: Can you post the code for how you get your data? There are many different ways to achieve that, maybe there is something missing. And can you verify what happens when you log 'await this.userRepositroy.save(user);'? As a result user.person.id should exist. Then we know that the save method works.

Comment: I have updated the question again with the console log after POST request. (I have more columns in the real project as you can see)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load the ID, or work with the ID alone (i.e. to set a relationship without loading the target entity), just declare the relation id column as follow:

```
  @OneToOne(
    (type) => Personal,
    (personal) => personal.user,
    { cascade: true, eager: true }
  )
  personal!: Personal;

  @Column('int')
  personalId!: personal;
```

if you need it to be nullable, just use `@Column('int', { nullable: true })`.

TypeORM will recognize the column since it has the same name and will not duplicate schema commands, while you can use the relation ID directly.

Comment: When I try to do this the data is not even going to the database because the ID would like to be null and it doesn't allow it to be. I have no idea why it is still remaining null... I actually tried everything.

Comment: Maybe you should add `@JoinColumn` too, but the null problem should not be present since TypeORM will insert the value automatically due to column equivalence

Comment: I feel sorry for my bad understanding, but I just want to be really sure: have you tried both of them at the same time like `@JoinColumn() @Column('int') personalId: number;` ?

Comment: Ok, I was suggesting to use *both* of them at the same time

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I tried it too... No success :(